# Python: invalid syntax: <string>, line 1, pos 16

Tags: python

I have developed a code in Python in which -in order to run the program- I need to take some arguments from the command line. But I am getting continuously the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
invalid syntax: <string>, line 1, pos 16
```

I have the faintest idea what is wrong with my code. So, I present my code below in case someone could help me:

```
import QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil as du
import QSTK.qstkutil.tsutil as tsu
import QSTK.qstkutil.DataAccess as da
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import math
import copy
import QSTK.qstkstudy.EventProfiler as ep
import csv
import sys
import argparse


def readData(li_startDate, li_endDate, ls_symbols):
    #Create datetime objects for Start and End dates (STL)
    dt_start = dt.datetime(li_startDate[0], li_startDate[1], li_startDate[2])
    dt_end = dt.datetime(li_endDate[0], li_endDate[1], li_endDate[2])

    #Initialize daily timestamp: closing prices, so timestamp should be hours=16 (STL)
    dt_timeofday = dt.timedelta(hours=16)

    #Get a list of trading days between the start and end dates (QSTK)
    ldt_timestamps = du.getNYSEdays(dt_start, dt_end, dt_timeofday)

    #Create an object of the QSTK-dataaccess class with Yahoo as the source (QSTK)
    c_dataobj = da.DataAccess('Yahoo', cachestalltime=0)

    #Keys to be read from the data
    ls_keys = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'actual_close']

    #Read the data and map it to ls_keys via dict() (i.e. Hash Table structure)
    ldf_data = c_dataobj.get_data(ldt_timestamps, ls_symbols, ls_keys)
    d_data = dict(zip(ls_keys, ldf_data))

    return [d_data, dt_start, dt_end, dt_timeofday, ldt_timestamps]


def marketsim(cash,orders_file,values_file):

    orders = pd.read_csv(orders_file,index_col='Date',parse_dates=True,header=None)
    ls_symbols = list(set(orders['X.4'].values))
    df_lastrow = len(orders) - 1
    dt_start = dt.datetime(orders.get_value(0, 'X.1'),orders.get_value(0, 'X.2'),orders.get_value(0, 'X.3'))
    dt_end = dt.datetime(orders.get_value(df_lastrow, 'X.1'),orders.get_value(df_lastrow, 'X.2'),orders.get_value(df_lastrow, 'X.3') + 1 )    
    #d_data = readData(dt_start,dt_end,ls_symbols)
    #Initialize daily timestamp: closing prices, so timestamp should be hours=16 (STL)
    dt_timeofday = dt.timedelta(hours=16)

    #Get a list of trading days between the start and end dates (QSTK)
    ldt_timestamps = du.getNYSEdays(dt_start, dt_end, dt_timeofday)

    #Create an object of the QSTK-dataaccess class with Yahoo as the source (QSTK)
    c_dataobj = da.DataAccess('Yahoo', cachestalltime=0)

    #Keys to be read from the data
    ls_keys = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'actual_close']

    #Read the data and map it to ls_keys via dict() (i.e. Hash Table structure)
    df_data = c_dataobj.get_data(ldt_timestamps, ls_symbols, ls_keys)
    d_data = dict(zip(ls_keys, ldf_data))

    ls_symbols.append("_CASH")
    trades = pd.Dataframe(index=list(ldt_timestamps[0]),columns=list(ls_symbols))
    current_cash = cash
    trades["_CASH"][ldt_timestamps[0]] = current_cash
    current_stocks = dict()
    for symb in ls_symbols:
        current_stocks[symb] = 0
        trades[symb][ldt_timestamps[0]] = 0

    for row in orders.iterrows():
        row_data = row[1]
        current_date = dt.datetime(row_data['X.1'],row_data['X.2'],row_data['X.3'],16)
        symb = row_data['X.4']
        stock_value = d_data['close'][symb][current_date]
        stock_amount = row_data['X.6']
        if row_data['X.5'] == "Buy":
            current_cash = current_cash - (stock_value*stock_amount)
            trades["_CASH"][current_date] = current_cash
            current_stocks[symb] = current_stocks[symb] + stock_amount
            trades[symb][current_date] = current_stocks[symb]
        else:
            current_cash = current_cash + (stock_value*stock_amount)
            trades["_CASH"][current_date] = current_cash
            current_stocks[symb] = current_stocks[symb] - stock_amount
            trades[symb][current_date] = current_stocks[symb]


    #trades.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
    #trades.fillna(method='bfill',inplace=False)
    trades.fillna(0)
    #alt_cash = current_cash
    #alt_cash = trades.cumsum()
    value_data = pd.Dataframe(index=list(ldt_timestamps),columns=list("V"))
    value_data = value_data.fillna(0)
    value_data = value_data.cumsum(axis=0)
    for day in ldt_timestamps:
        value = 0
        for sym in ls_symbols:
            if sym == "_CASH":
                value = value + trades[sym][day]
            else:
                value = calue + trades[sym][day]*d_data['close'][sym][day]
        value_data["V"][day] = value

    fileout = open(values_file,"w")
    for row in value_data.iterrows():
        file_out.writelines(str(row[0].strftime('%Y,%m,%d')) + ", " + str(row[1]["V"].round()) + "\n" )

    fileout.close()



def main(argv):

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Invalid arguments for marketsim.py. It should be of the following syntax: marketsim.py orders_file.csv values_file.csv"
        sys.exit(0)

    #initial_cash = int (sys.argv[1])
    initial_cash = 1000000
    ordersFile = str(sys.argv[1])
    valuesFile = str(sys.argv[2])

    marketsim(initial_cash,ordersFile,valuesFile)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The input I gave to the command line was:

```
python marketsim.py orders.csv values.csv
```

I guess that the problem lies either into the imports or probably into the main function(incl. the if below the `def main(argv)`

I have to point out that the files orders.csv and values.csv exist and are located into the same folder.

I hope have made everything clear.

So, I am looking forward to reading your answers community-mates! :D

Thank you!

Comment: As a base test, if you remove all your code, are you getting errors when you import those files and give them their alias'

Comment: @Fallenreaper everything is fine by doing what you proposed.

Comment: check you are not having *space* / *tab* combination in your code for the indentation

Comment: Does it crash if you call with the wrong number of arguments? If not, put a return statement into the start of the marketsim function and move it downwards until the error occurs. My suspicion is that at some point a syntactically invalid string is evaluated (probably in one of the imported modules).

Comment: @anonymous Thank you, but unfortunately I have already checked it!

Comment: Then there might be syntax error in any of the function you are calling from imported modules. Try as mentioned by Dr.V

Comment: @Dr.V I did it but it did not work. That is, I put a return statement at the first line of marketsim function before even reading the input file "orders_file" and the same error had occurred.

Comment: But if you put `return` into the main function, it does not give the error before calling `marketsim`? Heisenberg?

Comment: @Dr.V same results, I put the `return` into the main (starting from the very beginning of my code-the first line) but the same error had occurred

Comment: Well, but then it must be the imports!? Just keep on removing stuff until you can see which line stinks [primitive delta debugging] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Debugging).

Comment: @Dr.V  Is there any chance additional imports to be the cause?

Comment: @Dr.V I just skipped the function call and put the following statement: `print initial_cash, ordersFile, valuesFile`...and guess what? The same d@$n error!!